# How to pass variables to driver execute script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to pass some variables to js executor, but no luck.
I've tried just about everything, but although it prints variables, the executor just doesn't do anything on webpage.

Here's the code:

```
    strings = ["ABC","DEF"]

elems = [i.text for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(title)]

import itertools
from json import dumps

for string, elem in zip(strings, elems):
    print(string, elem)

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = '{}'".format(string), elem)
   # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = ' + dumps(string)'", elem)
   # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1]", string, elem)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: where have you decalred you driver?

Comment: Driver was declared before that, this is just the part of the code that's been bugging me :)

Comment: Code looks good, check for iframes.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried without variable "string", used a word and it worked. So, the variable is what's not being posted, don't know why. And the "elem" is title in google search results. Any clues?

Comment: maybe first assing text to variable and display it to see what you really use. OR create minimal working code with real URL so we could run it to see problem on real HTML. At this moment code looks good and we have not clue what is wrong - so we can't help you.

Comment: I don't understand why you get `i.text` and use this text as `arguments[0]`. As for me you try to insert HTML to not existing element. As for me you should use `i` instead of `i.text` - and this can make all problem.

Comment: What is `title` in `find_elements_by_xpath()`? If you want to replace text in title then you should use `i` instead of `i.text`

Comment: Ugh, @furas, I luv you :) It was the i.text that was causing the problem. Now it all works. Thanks a lot:) Please make it as an answer so I can tick it, ok? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `innerHTML` then you should use `i` instead of `i.text`.

And if you want to use `arguments[1]` then you have to use values in `execute_script(...)` in different order `elem,string` instead of `string,elem`

```
from selenium import webdriver
             
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
 
strings = ["ABC", "DEF"]

title = '//title'
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(title)

for string, elem in zip(strings, elems):
    print(string, elem)

    # WORKS
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = '{}'".format(string), elem)
    
    # WORKS - needs different order `elem, string` instead of `string, elem`
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1]", elem, string)
    #time.sleep(2)
```

---

**BTW:**

If you want to append new text to existing `title` then you should use

```
"arguments[0].text += arguments[1]"
```

It may need also to add space between old and new text

```
"arguments[0].text += ' ' + arguments[1]"
```